# Using ::warning or ::error with col and endColumn parameters has no effect

Tags: github-actions

According to the [Workflow commands for GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-a-warning-message) documentation, I can pass a `col` and `endColumn` parameter to indicate a position in a file where the warning/error occurs. For example, I am writing out the line below, following the docs:

```
::warning title=Possible spelling mistake found.,file=README.md,line=3,col=30,endColumn=40::Possible replacements: «Docusates»
```

This does work, to an exent, in annotating the file in the Pull Request as shown in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot showing annotation of README file with the warning message]

However, nothing is apparently done with `col` and `endColumn`. I was hoping it would highlight the text in some way. I cannot find anything in the docs to indicate what these two parameters are used for, if not for that purpose.

Is this expected behavior? Or, am I doing something wrong?